# laravel time out error

Tags: apache, laravel-5, get

i have a project running in ubuntu-apache2 with laravel 5.3. The problem is that laravel works on some users but on others it doesn't. When you make the url request the page stays on hold, and you can´t see anything. It's strange because i have users that are using the app normally.

I saw the apache log and i can see the 302 request but not the answer. I change in site-avaible conf the document root to the root path and a I can see the indexes, so i think the problem is in the .htacces file, although I have not made any changes. This is my .conf ->

```
ServerAdmin serveradmin@serveradmin.com
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias theurlofmypage
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/extranet/public
<Directory "/var/www/html/extranet/public">

AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

And this is the .htacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

A 302 is most likely a Laravel response, not an apache thing seeing you redirect with a 301 as far as I can tell. 
I had an instance where this drove me nuts too. It happend because I had putten a redirect() somewhere in the code and some requests triggerd it. It redirected back to itself to a part with a wrong namespace which didn't fly.
All I can recommend is temporarily disable middleware and Requests (validation). If that doesn't work try to find all your abort's and redirect()'s.

Comment: First thanks for your answer. But the problem is on the main page. I use the Auth::route that redirects to the login view. I didn't make any change on that. It's driving me crazy...